# Is there a shorthand for typing objects in place?

Tags: typescript

I find it overly verbose to write the long version, even when I shorten function definitions argument names with underscore.

So I want to turn something valid like this:

```
const myObj: {
    myProp: ((_: (_:string) => void) => void)[]
} = {
    myProp: []
};
```

Into something shorter and where I'm not writing the prop name twice, like this:

```
const myObj = {
    myProp<(:((:string) => void) => void)[]>: []
};
```

Or whatever syntax TS allows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type assertion to give a more specific type to the empty array (although I don't recommend this for non-empty arrays as the assertion might allow assignment of items that don't really match the type fully):

```
const myObj = {
    myProp: [] as Array<(_: (_:string) => void) => void>
};
```

I also changed to use `Array<>` as it is more readable for complex item types.